# Strange behaviour go to definition shortcut when ~/.config/nvim is symlink

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I have strange behaviour for `gd` shortcut but only when `~/.config/nvim` directory is symlink to `nvim -> /home/user/dotfiles/nvim`

[image]

I have ls-zero config and shortcut for current buffer

```
lsp.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  local opts = {buffer = bufnr, remap = false}

  vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", function() vim.lsp.buf.definition() end, opts)
 
end)
```

When `~/.config/nvim` is standalone directory then `gd` shortcut works well - jumps to selected definition

Any suggestions/ideas how to fix this? Of course at least I made bash script to copy dir from repo dir to final location :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in lsp configuration: when I commented out that line:

```
lsp.nvim_workspace()
```

the `gd` command starts works well :P